# In Qt embedded 4.8.4, USB keyboard doesn't work properly

Tags: qt, keyboard, arm, embedded

When I start embedded Qt GUI application from a serial port or a terminal via SSH, then type input from wireless USB keyboard, I almost cannot see input on console screen. I have set
export QWS_KEYBOAD=TTY:/dev/tty1
or
export QWS_KEYBOAD=linuxinput:/dev/input/event2
for 
/dev/input/by-path/platform-ehci-omap.0-usb-0:2.2:1.0-event-kbd -> ../event2, it doesn't work too.
But If I start my application from console screen which is /dev/tty1, it works fine. 
My issue is my application starts automatically after reboot, it doesn't respond to keyboard input. Any ideas?

Comment: QWS_KEYBOARD with an 'R'?  I guess that is a typo?  It probably has to do with permissions.  The OS (Linux?) will not let you grab the console.

Comment: Sorry for my typo, I run embedded linux on BB. But sometimes I  saw a few inputs.

Comment: I found it could be caused by weak USB signal. If the application starts automatically, I need to disable auto login, otherwise it has same problem.